# I'm missing something on a kafka producer, I'm sending a fix letter into all topics

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have something really strange on my kafka producer in .NET. Everything is working fine I can create and send the messages, create topics and whatever i want but i have a part of the message that is fixed.

I create a string called "msg" if a print it on the console it is perfect, but it gets on the consumer with an additional "b'" on the front and i really don't understand from where is coming from.

```
using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(config).Build())
                {
                    producer.ProduceAsync(topic: "anr", new Message<Null, string> { Value = msg });
                    producer.Flush(timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                    Console.WriteLine(msg);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
```

Let' said that my message that i have created is "messages test" but on the consumer i got "b'message test" and is strange because even if i change topic it is always there.

So weird..

Comment: Are you pasting the message from somewhere by any chance? I had the same problem when I was pasting it from one text editor, it used to introduce an extra 'b'  character which is some space character. This character will not be visible on the console, but it will get appended in the message.

Comment: The message is created by a producer .net so no copy and paste. thanks